# TFS2010 for SSMS 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, source-control

SSMS 2012 does not work with VSS 6. We installed modern source control, TFS 2010 server.

Then I Installed Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider 2010.
However the only choice for Source control  plug-in in SSMS 2012 is still  VSS6.
My VS2010 works just fine, I could connect to TFS in a team explorer.

How to add TFS as a second source code control plugin in SSMS 2012?

Answer (score 8):

To use SQL Server Management Studio 2012 with Team Foundation Server (TFS) source control, you need to first install the [Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider 2010 32-bit](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bce06506-be38-47a1-9f29-d3937d3d88d6) or [Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider 2012 32-bit](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b5b5053e-af34-4fa3-9098-aaa3f3f007cd).

Then you will be able to select TFS as one of the source control providers under: **Tools > Options > Source Control > Plug-In Selection.**

Note that one of the pre-requisites to using the MSSCCI Provider is that you also have [Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=329) (the TFS client) installed on your machine. This is because it installs the TFS Object Model assemblies that the MSSCCI Provider uses to talk to TFS.

Comment: Your first link points to a 2010 version which doesn't appear to be compatible with SSMS 2012.

Comment: This is probably the correct link then
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b5b5053e-af34-4fa3-9098-aaa3f3f007cd